# Windows linking to libcurl_a.lib

Tags: c, windows, libcurl, cl, cl.exe

I built libcurl following the instructions for building libcurl as a static library in the curl/winbuild directory to the letter. It spat out a `libcurl_a.lib`, a collection of `.h` files, which I moved into folders that I promptly added to the PATH. I then attempt to build my program with the command

```
cl (*my source files*) /IC:/PATH_addon/include libcurl_a.lib Ws2_32.lib Wldap32.lib /DCURL_STATICLIB /link /LIBPATH:C:/PATH_addon/lib
```

Note:

- I am building from the command line as the code was not written in an IDE, or on this machine
- C:/PATH_addon/ is a folder where I dump all the things that need to be linked into path (it is linked to my path) so that I don't pollute the default path, or my system32 folder

However when I run the command, it tells me that there are 12 unresolved symbols:

```
libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64
libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64
libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64
libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64
libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___time64
libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
libcurl_a.lib(curl_sspi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__read referenced in function _curlx_read
OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__read
libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__write referenced in function _curlx_write
OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__write
libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___gmtime64 referenced in function _Curl_gmtime
libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strerror referenced in function _Curl_strerror
libcurl_a.lib(curl_threads.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___beginthreadex referenced in function _Curl_thread_create
libcurl_a.lib(smb.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___getpid referenced in function _smb_format_message
libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__close referenced in function _file_done
OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__close
libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__open referenced in function _file_connect
OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__open
libcurl_a.lib(mime.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__access referenced in function _curl_mime_filedata
OLDNAMES.lib(access.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__access
MSVCRT.lib(_chandler4gs_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
```

Why can't these symbols be resolved, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: These are plain CRT functions, defined in msvcrt.lib.  Ensure that the LIB environment variable is set correctly so the linker can find it.  Or add it to /LIBPATH.

Comment: Thank you @chkdrv! The content of your question actually helped me resolve linking issues with curl. I missed linking Wldap32.lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (thanks in part to the incredible @Hans Passant):

Adding the `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT` flag fixed the issue and allowed for a successful compile and execution.